# Different between Eff monad and Free monad

Tags: scala, functional-programming

`Eff monad` looks so much better and more usable than monad transformers and can replace boilerplates with monad transformation, but `Free monad` can make the exact same thing with providing division between execution and program definition, as consequence `Eff monad` looks like overhead. If I missed some nuance, please correct me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Monad transformers is what you want to use for you every day programs, it let's you `map` and `flatMap` on `T` in `Task[Option[T]]`, for example.

`Free` and `Eff` solve a different problem: they let you write *multiple interpreters* for your programs (which is most likely overkill for your everyday application). They are both used to build monadic expressions. `Eff` lets you "split the labor" of interpretation into multiple interpreters, while with `Free` you typically transform expression "all at once" from their `Free` structure to another monad.

Comment: Does `Free` and  `Eff` differ only with concept "split the labor" of interpretation?

Comment: Yes, this is my understanding. Note that by "only" in the case you refer to a series of 3 research papers.  It seems the entire field of *effect systems* is essentially glorified interpreter patterns with adequate split of labor.

Comment: I think from the papers, Free and Eff were created with the ambition that they can completely remove all boilerplates associated with creating new monads. But currently, they are still working on reducing the performance overhead.